# JSON Parsing in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON data which is something like the following ::

```
{"product":["{productTitle=ABCD , productImage=/abcd.jpg, productPath=CDEF.html, productPrice=$299}","{productTitle=EFGH, productImage=xxxx.jpg, productPath=ggfft.html, productPrice=$299}"]}
```

I my JSP page I am trying to process the data and use it .

Following is the function that I am using to parse each node of the response .

```
success : function(data) {
                            alert("successs");
                            alert('data.product' + data.product);
                            $.each(data.product, function(index) {
                                     alert(data.product[index].productTitle);


                                 });

                         },
```

Here `alert('data.product' + data.product);`  gives me the alert with the whole JSON which is under the product node .

`alert(data.product[index].productTitle);`  -- This alert is showing as "undefined" .

I need help to parse it the JSON and print each of the "**productTitle**"

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.product` is an array of strings not objects or JSON, you'll have to parse the strings to get the data.

you can use regex to transform the string to JSON an then JSON.parse or $.parseJSON to convert it to js objects but its a bit messy, see http://jsfiddle.net/nQE6J

```
$.each(data.product, function(index) {
    alert(JSON.parse(data.product[index].replace(/=/g, ':').replace(/([a-z\.A-Z\$\/\d]+)/g, '"$1"')).productTitle);
});
```

Comment: how can that be achieved ? I am newbie in jquery . Sorry for the terminologies .

Comment: @sabyasachi Can you change the format of the data to be JSON inside data.product?

Comment: Its tough for me to change the format the JSON is coming with . Can't we use this format and parse it ?

Comment: @sabyasachi you can use regex to transform the string to JSON an then JSON.parse or $.parseJSON to convert it to js objects but its a bit messy , see http://jsfiddle.net/nQE6J/

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse(data)
```

should do the trick.

Edit: I see that it is not even JSON inside the string. Use Musa's answer to transform it into JSON and then use `JSON.parse(data)` as I suggested initially.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   var jdata = JSON.parse(data);
   $.each(jdata.product, function(index, productdetail) {
         alert(productdetail.productTitle);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

The json you give is

```
{
"product":[
"{productTitle=ABCD , productImage=/abcd.jpg, productPath=CDEF.html, productPrice=$299}",
"{productTitle=EFGH, productImage=xxxx.jpg, productPath=ggfft.html, productPrice=$299}"
]
}
```

However you have to change above into

```
{
"product":[
    {"productTitle":"ABCD"  , 
     "productImage":"/abcd.jpg", 
     "productPath":"CDEF.html", "productPrice":"$299"},
    ....
]
}
```

So
`data.product[0].productTitle` is "ABCD"

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
contentType : "application/json"
```

to you request (and in the Response header, which should be done automatically by your webserver). jQuery then automatically interprets the Repsonse as JSON object and parses it.

Comment: response.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");

Comment: does your webserver answer with "contentType : "application/json" 
"?